# How do I change the text font color on the Vulcan template in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, fonts, colors, textcolor

I have my own website and I am currently using the Vulcan template on Wordpress and I want to change a texts font color. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, if there is a will there is a way.

**Are you changing an element inside a post?**
Open up your page/post editor and switch the editor to "Text" mode (look to the far right on the editor) and keep reading.

**Are you changing a "hard-coded" element in a file?**
Open up the file in question with your favorite text-editor and keep reading.

**Changing multiple elements?**
Look into using CSS classes (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors). Add your classes to your HTML elements using the `class` attribute.

**Changing just one element?**
Look into using the `style` (http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/core-attributes/style) attribute on your element.